# Mongo CastError

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Catch this error in mongoose, need quick help, please.
I need to add id to tasks in Courses to my new Task, which i created. But i have problems with type od id's.

This my Schemas

```
const {Schema, model, Types} = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, maxLength: 200},
    imgSrc: {type: String},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    tasks: [ {type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'HomeWork'} ]
});

module.exports = model('Course', schema)


const {Schema, model, Types} = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    task: {type: String, required: true},
    courseId: {type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course'}
});

module.exports = model('HomeWork', schema)
```

This my method to add HomeWork and Courses:

```
router.post('/createtask', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body)
        const {title, task, courseName} = req.body

        const existingCourse = await Course.findOne({ title: courseName })
        const courseId = existingCourse._id

        if (existingCourse) {

            const existing = await HomeWork.findOne({ title: title })

            if (existing) {
                return res.json({ task: existing })
            }
            const newTask = new HomeWork({
                title, task, courseId
            })

            const saveTask = await newTask.save()

            const taskId = saveTask._id

            console.log("Id задания: ", taskId)

            console.log("Course ID: ", saveTask.courseId)

            try {
                let id = Types.ObjectId(taskId)
                console.log("id to ObjectId ", id)

                const afterUPD = await Course.update( {_id: existingCourse._id}, { $push: {tasks: { id } } } )
                console.log(afterUPD)
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }

            console.log("ASTER: ", afterUPD)

            res.status(201).json({ newTask })
        }

        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Курс не найден, попробуйте снова' })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова' })
    }
})
```

Catch error like this:

```
[0] MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: 5f58d8dff60610171068711d }" at path "tasks"
[0]     at new CastError (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
[0]     at model.Query.exec (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4341:21)
[0]     at model.Query.Query.then (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4433:15)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
[0]   messageFormat: undefined,
[0]   stringValue: '"{ id: 5f58d8dff60610171068711d }"',
[0]   kind: 'ObjectId',
[0]   value: { id: 5f58d8dff60610171068711d },
[0]   path: 'tasks.0',
[0]   reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
[0]       at new ObjectID (S:\WSProj\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
[0]       at castObjectId (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
[0]       at ObjectId.cast (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:267:12)
[0]       at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1031:12)
[0]       at SchemaArray.SchemaType._applySetters (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:998:28)
[0]       at SchemaArray._applySetters (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:291:45)
[0]       at SchemaArray.SchemaType.applySetters (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1024:16)
[0]       at castUpdateVal (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:475:22)
[0]       at walkUpdatePath (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:242:26)
[0]       at castUpdate (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:94:7)
[0]       at model.Query._castUpdate (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4514:10)
[0]       at castDoc (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4543:18)
[0]       at model.Query._updateThunk (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3728:20)
[0]       at model.Query.<anonymous> (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3801:23)
[0]       at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _execUpdate] (S:\WSProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
[0]       at S:\WSProj\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33
[0] }
```

Cant resolve this problem. Try to use mongo.Types.ObjectId(), its not working.

Comment: I think `taskId` is already an `ObjectId`, so you don't need to construct one explicitly. Just use `taskId` instead of `id`.

Comment: See also this problem.MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ taskId: 5f58e6a9d9f9f8270896097a }" at path "tasks"